# Download a webpage and media

Tags: python

I need to download a webpage and all its media (like css javascript and images) to make a sort of backup (like firefox does when you click on File -> Save) with python.

Is there any library to do that or I shall create my own one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly Python, but there's a pretty standard *nix utility called [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) which you can call from a Python script that will do this.

Comment: yeah! just found this: http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#head-885de428f3bea3d05abc99e24ecff2425d42cb3e I'm just trying it ;)

thanks :)