# Downloading Webpage & Media Python (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a python application that needs to be able to download all media, javascript, etc. onto the computer. It MUST be able to run on Windows, which I why I can't use wget (as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035324/download-a-webpage-and-media). Does anyone know of a library/module for this?

EDIT: I have tried `wget` as suggested by @JakobBowyer, but I would prefer a python library. Ideas?

Comment: is now a bad time to say http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: @JakobBowyer Kinda, but if this is Windows-compatible then I guess it works. If you know of any alternatives, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can download wget on windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) like suggested in the comments on your post, or use the urllib and os modules to do this.

Comment: I tried urllib, but it didn't download media. Add that to the fact that it's part of the legacy interface (to be deprecated in the future) and I pretty much gave up on it.